# Formatting dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, formatting

I have a data in dataGridView like this:

```
codetrans | datetrans | codeitem
----------+-----------+----------
 CDTRS1   | 2015/9/14 |  BR01
 CDTRS2   | 2015/9/15 |  BR02
 CDTRS2   | 2015/9/15 |  BR03
```

My question is how to change forecolor when codetrans and datetrans is the same, but codetrans and datetrans index won't change?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.DataGridView.Equals(row.Cells[0].Value))
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

and I'm stuck in here.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what are you trying to achieve. Assuming you want to indicate a duplicate row. Let first define some helpers:

```
static bool EqualKeys(DataGridViewRow x, DataGridViewRow y, string[] keyNames)
{
    foreach (var keyName in keyNames)
        if (!Equals(x.Cells[keyName].Value, y.Cells[keyName].Value)) return false;
    return true;
}
static bool IsDuplicateRow(DataGridView dg, int rowIndex, string[] keyNames)
{
    var row = dg.Rows[rowIndex];
    for (int i = rowIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (EqualKeys(row, dg.Rows[i], keyNames)) return true;
    return false;
}
static bool IsDuplicateRowCell(DataGridView dg, int rowIndex, int columnIndex, string[] keyNames)
{
    return keyNames.Contains(dg.Columns[columnIndex].Name) &&
        IsDuplicateRow(dg, rowIndex, keyNames);
}
```

Now you can use them from your `CellFormatting` event:

```
if (IsDuplicateRowCell((DataGridView)sender, e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex, keyNames))
{
    // Do whatever you like with the cell style 
    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    // ...
}
```

Here is a full sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samples
{
    static class Test
    {
        static bool EqualKeys(DataGridViewRow x, DataGridViewRow y, string[] keyNames)
        {
            foreach (var keyName in keyNames)
                if (!Equals(x.Cells[keyName].Value, y.Cells[keyName].Value)) return false;
            return true;
        }
        static bool IsDuplicateRow(DataGridView dg, int rowIndex, string[] keyNames)
        {
            var row = dg.Rows[rowIndex];
            for (int i = rowIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                if (EqualKeys(row, dg.Rows[i], keyNames)) return true;
            return false;
        }
        static bool IsDuplicateRowCell(DataGridView dg, int rowIndex, int columnIndex, string[] keyNames)
        {
            return keyNames.Contains(dg.Columns[columnIndex].Name) && IsDuplicateRow(dg, rowIndex, keyNames);
        }
        class Data
        {
            public string codetrans { get; set; }
            public string datetrans { get; set; }
            public string codeitem { get; set; }
        }
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var dataSet = new List<Data>
            {
                new Data { codetrans="CDTRS1", datetrans ="2015/9/14", codeitem="BR01" },
                new Data { codetrans="CDTRS2", datetrans ="2015/9/15", codeitem="BR02" },
                new Data { codetrans="CDTRS2", datetrans ="2015/9/15", codeitem="BR03" },
                new Data { codetrans="CDTRS2", datetrans ="2015/9/15", codeitem="BR03" },
                new Data { codetrans="CDTRS2", datetrans ="2015/9/15", codeitem="BR05" },
            };
            var form = new Form();
            var dg = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = form };
            var keyNames = new[] { "codetrans", "datetrans", "codeitem" };
            dg.CellFormatting += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (IsDuplicateRowCell((DataGridView)sender, e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex, keyNames))
                    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            };
            dg.CellValueChanged += (sender, e) => ((DataGridView)sender).Invalidate();
            dg.DataSource = dataSet;
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListView instead.

Code is very simple.

```
yourListView.Items[1].ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: what can do it in datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

You can try my code:

```
yourDataGirdview.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
yourDataGirdview.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
yourDataGirdview.Rows[0].Cells[1].Style.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

In your case:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.DataGridView.Equals(row.Cells[0].Value))
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            row.Cells[1].Style.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Can you describe in detail what do you expect?

Comment: I have 3 data in my datagrid, I want give backcolor or fontcolor when have same codetrans and datetrans.

Comment: That means you change colour when you add data for each row in your datagridview? If yes, you should do it when you add row instead of using CellFormatting event. That will never works.

Comment: No when add data, but have same data codetrans and datetrans.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

EXAMPLE:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewRichTextBox
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadDatGridView();
        }

        private readonly DataTable _table = new DataTable();
        private void LoadDatGridView()
        {
            _table.Columns.Add("Column1");
            _table.Rows.Add("CDTRS1 2015/9/14 BR01");
            _table.Rows.Add("CDTRS2 2015/9/15 BR02");
            _table.Rows.Add("CDTRS2 2015/9/15 BR03");
            _table.AcceptChanges();

            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = _table;

            foreach (DataRow row in _table.Rows)
            {
                var splits = row[0].ToString().Split(' ');
                var value = string.Format("{0} {1}", splits[0], splits[1]);
                using (var rich = new RichTextBox{Text = row[0].ToString()})
                {
                    if (IsValueExist(value))
                    {
                        rich.Text = row[0].ToString();
                        rich.Select(0, value.Length);
                        rich.SelectionColor = Color.Brown;
                        row[0] = rich.Rtf;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rich.Text = row[0].ToString();
                        rich.SelectAll();
                        rich.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
                        row[0] = rich.Rtf;
                    }
                }
            }
            _table.AcceptChanges();
        }

        private bool IsValueExist(string value)
        {
            return dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Count(row => row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(value)) > 1;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Source: [RichTextBox Cell in a DataGridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31823/RichTextBox-Cell-in-a-DataGridView)