# Can I show the Excel file in a Winform/C# application and keep the format?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

sorry for my bad English. I will try to summarize my question!

I am making a software using C# and Winform to compare 2 Excel files. I am a student and new to C#. Many post tell that I should read an Excel file and using Data Gridview to show the content. However, I can not keep the format.

My question is: Can I show an Excel file in Winform and keep the format of the file? And Can I view 2 file Excel side by side in Winform?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your question is rather vague. You should have a look at libraries that are useful for reading Excel spreadsheets in C#. A notable one is EPPlus: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/

Comment: Another is the *OpenXML SDK*. Be forewarned that reading all the features of an Excel file (for example, styles and formatting) and using that to format a different grid tool will not be a simple task

Comment: You can format the datagrid view as well, look e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-format-data-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534779/formatting-datagridview).